# Back Arrow in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabs

I have 3 tabs with lists of different video.In first tab when I click the item of my lyst the new activity started and play the video,this activity have parent my main activity with lists and this mainactivity have 1tab as main tab.But when I click in item in 2 tab,thid videoplayer started too,but back arrow go to main activity and main activity have 1 tab main,not second.It's very hard,but Im trying to explain:-)
How can I change this behavior,to go to 2 tab when click back arrow?

Comment: Add the current fragment to backstack,

Answer (score 0):

If when you have a toolbar then just add the following code in the onCreate. What this will do, it will work as the Back key of the smartphone. so it will close the current activity, and bring you back to what ever was on.

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  if (toolbar != null) {
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
      public void onClick(View v) { finish(); } });
   }
```